# SQL: How to COUNT the number of keys that appear in a certain number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have the following two SQL tables `dog` and `toy`:

`dog`

| id | gender |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |

`toy`

| toy_id | dog_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

We want to find out how many female dogs have a certain 0 toys, 1 toy, 2 toys... A value of `2` in the gender column indicates the dog is female.

The answer should be as seen below because dogs 1 and 2 are both female and have 2 toys, where as dog 3 is female and has 0 toys:

| num_toys | num_dogs |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

What SQL query will get me to this answer? The query below gives me a table with all the female dogs and their toys. How do I expand on this to aggregate?

```
Select toys.toy_id, toys.dog_id
From toys
Where toys.toy_id IN (
    SELECT dog.id
    From dog
    Where dog.gender = 2
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You could use two levels of aggregation:

```
select num_toys, count(*)
from (select d.id, count(t.dog_id) as num_toys
      from dogs d left join
           toys t
           on t.dog_id = d.id
      where d.gender = 2
      group by d.id
     ) d
group by num_toys;
```

The trick here is to use a `let join` in the subquery, so you can get dogs with no toys.